# Migrations File too Large preventing Migrate

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-migrations

In Django 2.2, I run makemigrations then migrate. I wait approx. 5-7 minutes and then I get "Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow."
"Current thread 0x0002094 (most recent call first):" yada yada 
"File "manage.py", line 17 in main
"File manage.py line 21 in "

End. I check the migrations file and the file is 4000 lines of code large. What do I do in this case? Should I make my own migration files, and if so, how?

Edit: gist.github.com/andrewcw825/9aab9ab2908e12f6d9f4047ac7fb2427 We also use Django-Tagulous. Unfortunately for secrecy, some things were added and others were removed. Some field names were changed and I believe one was removed. There are more migration.AddField since other models use the same tags, to which more migration.AddFields are added.

Comment: You probably should show your models, because I've never seen a 4k line migration file

Comment: 4k line migration file?  Wow.  Are you reverse engineering an existing schema?  Squashing an existing migration history?  You could break that migration file into multiple smaller ones I'd imagine.

Comment: can you copy your models here?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan https://gist.github.com/andrewcw825/9aab9ab2908e12f6d9f4047ac7fb2427 Unfortunately, the design is HIGHLY specific... Too specific unfortunately, but something I'm dealing with... The models are somewhat old, but, again, they're very specific. In the gist, I've renamed a bunch of things and edited out an ArrayField field, which should only affect 100 lines max. The package this project uses is Django-Tagulous, and there are two TagulousFields for each model. Each test# model inherited from a base model which is abstract.

Comment: And just diving deeper, I realized WHY it's so stinkin' large. It's not just those models that have fields which links to the tag tables. There are other models that ALSO have links to the tag tables, thus the "migrations.AddField(model_name='test2', name='publicTags' yada yada is not enough. I'd say 3/4 of the file is the main models whereas  the rest is a part of Tagulous making more tables for its tagging system.